# After updating Android studio Stuck on Preparing Workplace, in background Scanning file indexing not allowing to cancel it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-3.0

shows Codes Errors like in main activity
After updating Android studio to latest version 3.1.2 Stuck on Preparing Workplace, in background Scanning file indexing for indefinite time not allowing to cancel it

```
 <application>
  <component name="ActionsCollector">
  <counts>
  <entry action="$Copy" count="13" />
  <entry action="$Delete" count="10" />
  <entry action="$Paste" count="525" />
  <entry action="$SelectAll" count="9" />
 </counts>
 <component>
 </application>
```

.... with many tags like these

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same for me on Android Studio 4.1. Closing and opening again fixed me the error. (MacOS X Catalina)